# How to convert any type (bmp,jpg etc.) image to DICOM image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to convert one image(bmp, jpg etc.) into another image of DICOM type. How its possible?
Please provide some help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are your original images standard image files (.bmp, .jpg, etc.) or are they DICOMs with jpg compression?